# Compile and run c++ code in a new terminal window?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

How can I make sublime compile and run my c/c++ code and open the output program in a new terminal window like what happens when I use an ide such as code blocks?

Comment: what platform are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glue plugin can do what you want.Check it out:
http://gluedocs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/